Double dipping data in regression models
I have a mixed effects regression model with outcome $y$, predictor $x$, and random effects for regions $j$ (I have one country with multiple regions):
$$ y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{ij} + u_j + \epsilon_{ij} $$
Where:

$y_{ij}$ is the outcome variable for observation $i$ in region $j$
$\beta_0$ is the fixed intercept
$\beta_1$ is the fixed slope coefficient
$x_{ij}$ is the predictor variable for observation $i$ in region $j$
$u_j$ is the random effect for region $j$, where $u_j \sim N(0, \sigma^2_u)$
$\epsilon_{ij}$ is the error term, where $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0, \sigma^2_\epsilon)$

I have rows of data for each region, but I also data for the country itself. I am wondering - do I include the data for the country in the model or exclude it (i.e. double dipping)?
My logic is that I should exclude it, since the model itself can be used to approximate the mean response for the country
$$ y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{ij} + u_j + \epsilon_{ij} $$
If we take the expected value of both sides:
$$ E[y_{ij}] = E[\beta_0 + \beta_1x_{ij} + u_j + \epsilon_{ij}] $$
$$ E[y_{ij}] = \beta_0 + \beta_1E[x_{ij}] + E[u_j] + E[\epsilon_{ij}] $$
We assume that $E[u_j] = 0$ (random effects have mean zero by definition) and $E[\epsilon_{ij}] = 0$ (errors have mean zero).
Therefore:
$$ E[y_{ij}] = \beta_0 + \beta_1\bar{x} $$
Where $\bar{x}$ is the average value of all $x$ in the data:
$$ \bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_j} x_{ij}}{\sum_{j=1}^J n_j} $$
To conclude, the country level data should not be included in the model. The region level data is sufficient and the country level mean response can be inferred from the model built on regional data. Is this ok?


PS: I think the same logic applies in the longitudinal setting:

$$ y_{ijt} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{ijt} + u_j + \epsilon_{ijt} $$
For the country-level mean response at time t,  take the expectation across all regions $j$ at that specific time point:
$$ E[y_{.t}] = E[\beta_0 + \beta_1x_{ijt} + u_j + \epsilon_{ijt}] $$
$$ E[y_{.t}] = \beta_0 + \beta_1E[x_{.t}] + E[u_j] + E[\epsilon_{ijt}] $$
Where $E[x_{.t}]$ is the mean of x across all regions at time $t$ (where $N_t$ is the total number of observations at time t):
$$ E[x_{.t}] = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_j} x_{ijt}}{N_t} $$
Since $E[u_j] = 0$ and $E[\epsilon_{ijt}] = 0$:
$$ E[y_{.t}] = \beta_0 + \beta_1E[x_{.t}] $$
Same conclusion : no need to re-include country level data

Unclear: Is region part of a country or is country part of a region?

I have one country with multiple regions

You only have one country?  Or you have multiple countries, each with multiple regions?

One country, multiple regions

If you only have one country then your "country data" is just going to be a variable that is the same for all data points (i.e., equivalent to an intercept term).

This sounds a bit trivial. If you have no variations in a particular variable, e.g. the country data is the same for all the data points, then it won't have any influence, on the final fitted values. But, it can influence the coefficients. Maybe that plays a role in your analysis? Why are you considering this question?

I am considering a regression model for Covid recovery in Canada. For each province (i.e. region), there is weekly information on the number of covid deaths and the number of covid vaccines. I thought that a mixed effects regression could be useful for this problem with a random effect placed on the province.

Please add new info as an edit to the post, not only as comments! Comments on this site are often seen by very few people, and can be deleted!
